# Why does VueJS not run production build?

Tags: node.js, docker, vue.js, docker-compose

I'm using a Docker-compose to initialize `ExpressJS + VueJS` and the `RestFull API`

This is docker compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  webserver:
    build: ./webserver
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    container_name: boleto_webserver
    networks:
       - boleto
    volumes:
       - ./webserver:/app/webserver
       - /app/webserver/node_modules  

  website:
    build: ./website
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    container_name: boleto_website
    networks:
       - boleto
    volumes:
       - ./website:/app/website
       - /app/webiste/node_modules

  api:
    build: ./api
    ports:
      - "3030:3030"
    container_name: boleto_api
    networks:
       - boleto
    volumes:
       - ./api:/app/api
       - /app/api/node_modules

networks:
  boleto:
    external: true
    name: boleto
```

In DockerFile inside Website (VueJS) I run a production build:

```
FROM node:12

WORKDIR /app/website

COPY package*.json ./
COPY . /app/website


RUN npm install 

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080


CMD ["npm","run","build"]
```

Browsing `localhost:3000` here is where the webserve is being launched I have this message:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/website/build/index.html'

Analyzing website logs:

```
  Note that the development build is not optimized.
  To create a production build, run npm run build.
```

If I run this applications separately, all them works well! Throwing inside a docker compose this happens! Anyone can help me?

### Updating

The webserver insists on run `script dev`, if I remove it, it does not compile

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "serve": "nodemon app.js",
    "dev": "nodemon app.js"
},



FROM node:12

WORKDIR /app/webserver

COPY package*.json ./
COPY . /app/webserver

RUN npm install && npm install nodemon

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm","run","serve"]
```

Comment: Why are you doing a `COPY` into `/app/website` when you're also mounting it as a volume with `./website:/app/website`?

Comment: I did it for testing, attempt to find out what is happening. I'll remove!

Comment: Like you said @Phil, how I'm mounting volume, remove COPY * in each dockerfile

Comment: You should remove the `volumes:`, so you're using the code that's built into the images (and the result of the `npm run build`).  Leave the Dockerfile as it is.

Comment: Following it @DavidMaze, I returned with `COPY` and now I receive a error running website `* ./src/main.js in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client/index.js (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js, multi (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js (webpack)-dev-server/client/index.js ./src/main.js`. I dont know if matter, but I dont have any webpack.config in my folder, and running outside docker, npm run build works

Comment: @DavidMaze, It is still running server `> project-2@0.1.0 serve /app/website 
> vue-cli-service serve

 INFO  Starting development server...`